# Testing a spring mvc rest controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm trying to create a very basic unit test for a spring mvc rest controller using the MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup method. I keep getting a 404 error. Below I list my Test application context, my test class, and my controller and the full stack trace. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
@Configuration
public class TestContext
{
    @Bean
    public Service service()
    {
        return mock(Service.class);
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestContext.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestUsingWebAppContextSetUp
{
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(MyController.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception
    {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/search?phoneNumber=5551112222"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
    }
}

public class MyController
{
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @RequestMapping("/search")
    public List<SearchResult> search(@RequestParam(value="phoneNumber") String phoneNumber)
    {
        System.out.println("search called");
        Search search = new Search();
        search.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        return service.search(search);
    }
}
```

> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>     at
>   org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:653)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:152)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.TestUsingWebAppContextSetUp.test(TestUsingWebAppContextSetUp.java:41)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javadoc of [`MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/MockMvcBuilders.html#standaloneSetup-java.lang.Object...-) states

> Build a `MockMvc` by registering one or more `@Controller`'s **instances** and
>   configuring Spring MVC infrastructure programmatically. This allows
>   full control over the instantiation and initialization of controllers,
>   and their dependencies, similar to plain unit tests while also making
>   it possible to test one controller at a time.

So you would use it as

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MyController()).build();
```

registering an actual instance. If you need this to be a Spring managed instance (which you probably do considering it has an `@Autowired` field), you'd have to get it from the `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: That works. I put a package visible setter on there for now so I could inject the Service. I'll try to get the context version going at some point. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why they have a method signature that takes a class if they expect you to instantiate it? The method signature implies they instantiate it and configure it.

Comment: @JoshChappelle To be fair, the method has a parameter type of `Object`. Since there's no "Controller" supertype, Spring has to accept every type which can potentially be annotated with `@Controller`.

Comment: Ahh didn't think about that. I didn't have the code in front of me when I made that comment. Now I just have to blame myself. :-)  Thanks again.